# Set dateTime on x-axis in PHPExcel?

Tags: phpexcel

The constructor of  PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues is:

```
construct   (       
$dataType = self::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,
$dataSource = null,
$formatCode = null,
$pointCount = 0,
$dataValues = array(),
$marker = null
```

)

I try to insert formatCode in this way:

```
$xAxisTickValues = array(
new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'worksheet!$A$2:$A$9', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', NULL, 4));
```

but it does not work? what is wrong here?

I use  PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_SCATTERCHART.

When I not use 'formatCode' my x-axis shows raw excel datetimes: 41760,41761..,and so on?instead of 2014-05-01 00:00:00,2014-05-01 12:00:00,..,

Does anyone have an good example on how to insert date and time on the x-axis in PHPExcel?

[image: See the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by making a hack in PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php line 493

```
   //$objWriter->writeAttribute('formatCode', "General");
      $objWriter->writeAttribute('formatCode', "dd/mm/yy\ hh:mm:ss;@");
```

Change the formatCode to "dd/mm/yy\ hh:mm:ss;@"

but why is "General" hard-coded !?

**UPDATE:**
Found another bug in PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php
Change $id2 to $id1. If you do not want problems with the y-axis label positioning?

```
if ($id1 > 0) {
                $objWriter->startElement('c:crossAx');
                    //$objWriter->writeAttribute('val', $id2);
                    $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', $id1);
                $objWriter->endElement();
```